# Print entire Cytoscape.js HTML5 canvas. Not just visible part

Tags: html5-canvas, cytoscape.js

I'm using Cytoscape.js and I'm trying to print out the entire diagram not just the visible parts. If the user is zoomed in, I expect it to print on numerous pages.

The best I've been able to get is only the visible part.

I'm surprised that printing isn't built into Cytoscape.js.

```
<script>
    function printCanvas() {

        var padding = 10; // padding around found objects
        var canvases = $('canvas');
        var context = canvases[2].getContext('2d');
        // find borders of a rectange covering all objects

        var newWidth = canvases[2].width;
        var newHeight = canvases[2].height;

        // create a new canvas
        var newcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        newcanvas.width = newWidth + 2 * padding;
        newcanvas.height = newHeight + 2 * padding;
        var newcontext = newcanvas.getContext('2d');

        // copy data to the new canvas
        newcontext.putImageData(context.getImageData(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), padding, padding);

        popup = window.open();
        popup.document.body.innerHTML = "<img src='" + newcanvas.toDataURL('png') + "' />";

        popup.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know about Cytoscape.js. but on canvas I would use a buffer canvas (not attached to the DOM or `display;none;) to draw the whole image and I would copy parts of this canvas on the visible one. From your code I see you are using 2 canvases. do you have both of them on the screen? If one of those 2 canvases is abuffer canvas you may recover the data with toDataURL()

Comment: I don't actually create the canvases, they're created by Cytoscape.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the entire graph as a PNG or JPG image:

```
cy.png({full: true})
```

For more details see the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/export).